# when i finish push my project,it report 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.RootBeanDefinition.setSingleton(Z)V'

Tags: java

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.RootBeanDefinition.setSingleton(Z)V
    at org.springframework.aop.config.ConfigBeanDefinitionParser.createPointcutDefinition(ConfigBeanDefinitionParser.java:520)
    at org.springframework.aop.config.ConfigBeanDefinitionParser.parsePointcutProperty(ConfigBeanDefinitionParser.java:493)
    at org.springframework.aop.config.ConfigBeanDefinitionParser.parseAdvisor(ConfigBeanDefinitionParser.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.config.ConfigBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ConfigBeanDefinitionParser.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.namespaces.DelegatingNamespaceHandlerResolver$ElementTrackingNamespaceHandler.parse(DelegatingNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1410)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$ErrorSuppressingBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeansConfig.java:1434)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1400)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:172)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$ToolingFriendlyBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(BeansConfig.java:1363)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$2.registerBeanDefinitions(BeansConfig.java:410)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$2.loadBeanDefinitions(BeansConfig.java:394)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$3.call(BeansConfig.java:453)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$3.call(BeansConfig.java:1)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:514)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

Comment: Please, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You have to give the code.

Comment: Generally this means that you have mismatch in version dependencies. The `org.springframework.aop.config.ConfigBeanDefinitionParser` expects a different version of `org.springframework.beans.factory.support.RootBeanDefinition` than is loaded. Make sure that all your dependencies are of the right (or at least compatible) version.